# Suspend Ubuntu server when inactive

Tags: server, suspend, power-management

I am running Ubuntu server for my home tinkering. I would like it to be able to suspend after period of inactivity, so that it saves power when not being used. The inactivity would be defined (ideally) as a period of time where no ssh connection was made and no requests were made to the 
web server which is run on the device (could be no connections to ports 80 and 443).

I tried sleepd but from what I understand it is outdated and I was not able to configure it properly for the problem described. I would like to ask you for suggestions of how to do this thing.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to run a cronjob, for example after every 5 minutes, then I'll run a script and on that script I would check for example when was the last time a ssh connection established or when was the last time which we got a http request, if it was more than X minute, then I will put the server at sleep. to find out these things we can have look at log files.

Comment: Can you please point me to the log files I should check for the events described? Thanx

Comment: Most of the operating system has some sort of shutdown on idle or hybernate. Usually it is in power management. Not sure if that is connected to your server applications. If it is a HTTP server you can ask the OS to shutdown if you did not get any request in the last 30 mins. Waking up on lan is a lot harder especially when you have encryption.